# javascript - Date() not accounting for Daylight Savings in website script, but does when executed in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, timezone, offset

I'm experiencing a problem with Firefox on RedHat when obtaining the current time, but it only seems to occur when executed within the script tags of our website. For my local timezone (GMT +0000), daylight savings is applied correctly and Date() produces IST/BST (GMT +0100). But when I test this for other timezones (EDT in this example), Daylight Savings is not being accounted for

When the system time is set to Fri Aug  1 07:42:56 EDT 2014, running:

```
console.log(new Date());
```

within the script tags of the website returns:

```
Fri Aug 01 2014 06:42:56 GMT-0500 (EDT)
```

However, when executing "new Date()" in the Firefox console, or on a test html page, the value returned is correct:

```
Fri Aug 01 2014 07:42:56 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

This problem doesn't occur on Windows either. I understand that the timezone offset is adjusted so that the time is technically correct, but I don't understand why it produces a different value when executed on our website. I'm completely perplexed.

Attempts so far:

- "new Date(Date.now())"
- Dojo date/stamp: "stamp.fromISOString(new Date().toISOString())"
- "new Date()" at various different areas of the website code base

Comment: Which time zone setting are you actually changing your computer to?  For US Eastern Time, it should be `"America/New_York"`.  Please confirm.   Also - Are you completely shutting down and restarting FireFox after changing the time zone before checking the results?

Comment: Wow... Restarting Firefox after each TZ change done the trick. I had a feeling this would happen with my first question on here! Thanks a million! For clarification, I was changing to a few different timezones for testing purposes, including "America/New_York", "Europe/Rome" etc. all with the same problem. What's the correct procedure to give you credit for this answer?

Comment: Posted as an answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this post on my blog](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers, including FireFox, require you fully restart the browser after changing time zones in order to provide correct results.  Closing all browser windows and restarting before testing again should fix the problem.

An exception to this is Internet Explorer on Windows, which subscribes to OS messages and resets correctly without restart.